# Kubernetes on localhost: setup certificates

Tags: kubernetes

I've just installed a kubernetes testinstallation directly on my fedora laptop using [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/v0.18.2/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.md).

After starting kube2sky I've noticed I can't connect to the kubernetes api since the certificates are required. kubernetes-ro is deprecated and no longer available on my machine, so I get the following errors:

E0627 15:58:07.145720       1 reflector.go:133] Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://10.254.0.1:443/api/v1beta3/services: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided
E0627 15:58:07.146844       1 reflector.go:133] Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get https://10.254.0.1:443/api/v1beta3/endpoints: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided

How can I setup the certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a common problem for folks that aren't running on setups that use salt to automatically configure system secrets on the master node (as GCE does). This has been fixed at head and should be fixed in the next release.

In the mean time, you can manually create a secret for the DNS service that contains a kubeconfig file for kube2sky to connect to the master. You can see how this is done on GCE by looking at the create-kubeconfig-secret function in [kube-addons.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/kube-addons/kube-addons.sh#L24) (when called with the username "system:dns"). The name of the resulting secret should be token-system-dns.

Comment: I share the same problem.  I often see the token being talked about in the same breath as the certificate. Does the token negate the need for a certificate? That's the part I don't understand.  It seems like you still need to make that https connection, which requires the cert?

Comment: The token and the certificate are used for different purposes. The certificate allows the client to verify the identify of the server (so that you can't be intercepted by a man-in-the-middle attacker). The token allows the server to identify the client (so that only verified clients can make connections). Together they allow the client and server to establish a secure authenticated connection. You can make a connection without the certificate (but with the token) but can't guarantee that someone won't steal your credentials by intercepting your traffic. Hope that helps.